# Java Mouse Listener error with UIManager SetLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, uimanager

The below code displays a `JFrame` with a `JMenu` and a [custom] `JPanel`.

I set the look-and-feel (LAF) to *Windows* LAF by calling method `UIManager.setLookAndFeel`

I click on the `JMenu` with the mouse and then I move the mouse onto the [custom] `JPanel` – while the menu is still visible. Then I click the mouse again and the `mousePressed` method of the `MouseListener` on my [custom] `JPanel` does not get called, even though the `mouseReleased` method does.

If I do not explicitly set the LAF, i.e. if I use the default LAF, it works fine.

How can I fix this?

Below are two classes: `MListen` and `Panel`. Class `MListen` declares a `main` method, so you can launch that class. Then you can perform the actions described above to reproduce the behavior. Class `Panel` is my custom `JPanel`.

I want the `mousePressed` method of the `MouseListener`, in class `Panel` to be called every time that the mouse is pressed if it is on the `Panel`.

- **MListen.java**

```java
package drawer.Main;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MListen extends JFrame{

    public MListen(){
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        setSize(800, 600);
        //setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        
        
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("file");
        JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("open");
        JButton b = new JButton("AB");
        file.add(b);
        
        bar.add(file);
        file.add(open);
        setJMenuBar(bar);
        
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
              
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                        | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                new MListen();  
            }  
        });  
    }

}
```

- **Panel.java**

```java
package drawer.Main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
    public float size;
    public Color color;
    public boolean DoDraw;

    public Panel(){
        addMouseListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        //System.out.println("Drag");
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Press");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("relese");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Try running the above code clicking on the red `JPanel`. The console will display "Press". Now click on the `JMenu` and then on the `JPanel` and "Press" will ***not*** be displayed in the console.

Thanks!

- **Edit**
  I need the UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
  Can I fix this without removing it?
  Also I need the MousePressed on the first time

Comment: @matt: why would it be a "focus issue" when a MouseListener doesn't require focus?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I thought the question was, I click on the menu and then I click on my jpanel and it misses the mouse pressed. Then they get a error because mouse pressed would be skipped. I almost expect that behavior. If a menu is showing, then I click on the jpanel. I don't really want something to happen.

Comment: Are you claiming it works as expected when you don't `UIManager.setLookAndFeel`?

Comment: Yes I tried removing it and it worked.

Comment: *"I tried removing it and it worked"* Tip: Add @matt (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Can it be a focus issue? If I open the JMenu on **click on one of the buttons** it calls the MousePressed. Only if a click on the JMenu and than on the JPanel it does not work. @HovercraftFullOfEels what can it be if not a focus issue?

Comment: @user15329314 You can check the focus, and you'll see the focus is gained and lost the same for both with or without the LAF being set. The MousePressedEvent is even being generated, but it doesn't go through to the panel. It seems like something is consuming the event along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bad answer, but it should work. You can capture all of the events before they're delegated.

This can be added to your JPanel constructor.

```
long eventMask = AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK;
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener( new AWTEventListener() {
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e){
                MouseEvent evt = (MouseEvent)e;
                if( evt.getSource() == this && evt.getId()==MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED ){
                    this.mousePressed(evt);
                    evt.consume();
                }
    }
}, eventMask );
```

This captures all mouse events check that they original from the correct panel, checks if it is a mousePressed event and calls the method.

This is good code for debugging, but not good to find in your project.

Comment: **I need the UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel"); Can I fix this without removing it?** This is the setLookAndFeel which I need. Is it possible to use this and detect mouse down on the first click?

Comment: @user15329314 I understand what you're after, I just left this up as an alternative example, since the windows LAF is not available on OSX. I guess the question is "where is the mouse pressed going".

Comment: yes I need the click position on the JPanel. Is it possible to get the position on the first click?

Comment: What should I use with setLookAndFeel? The setLookAndFeel in the example looks bad on my PC (I dont know if that looks the same on every PC)

Comment: @user15329314 I update my answer with an actual answer.

Comment: Thank you I will test this. But why is this a bad answer?

Comment: I changed some things and it works thanks! But why is this a bad answer?

Comment: @user15329314 because it should work the way you had it. If the look and feel changes that behavior, I wonder why. Either it is a bug, or an intended result. This solution registers an unofficial listener everytime you create that JPanel, for the life of the application. Not necessarily the life of the JPanel. It is also a memory leak, though you probably won't be creating enough of these JPanels to notice.

Comment: I think a better solution is to recognize, sometimes you'll have a mouse released that was not preceded by a mouse pressed, and make the application behave in a desired manner anyways.